# MVC 3 Razor view BeginForm is not posting to controller in FF, but works in IE 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a form in MVC 3 razor view that I am trying to post to my controller.

I need these:

1) Post the form to the controller action.

2) The action should do something with the data &return a string status (OK if success or NOK if failed)

3) Based on the result I might redirect the user after a brief delay.

4) I also want to prevent duplicate submission (if possible)

This is how my view looks (I trimmed it):

```
@model <MyNameSpace.Model>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Save";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyMaster.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "my_controller"))
{
  <div>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Host, new { @style = "width: 520px" })

      ... set other fields on the form ...

      <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public String Save(<ModelName> model)
{
   return "OK";
}
```

This seems working in IE9. But nothing happens in FF 4 or Opera. HttpFox shows no activity.

What is missing?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used firbug for this one. I used httpfox to see if any activity. I used firebug for DOM related stuff not posting to the server. How do I use it?

Comment: Check the Net tab, and look for JS errors in the Console tab.

Comment: No error in the console. Also Net tab just shows the requests for the .js files

Comment: This is most certainly a HTML-bug. It would help if you could also post thhe "... set other fields on the form ..." markup..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC it is considered good practice to have your controller actions return ActionResults instead of strings. This way proper content type headers will be set, etc...

So for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ModelName model)
{
    return Content("OK", "text/plain");
}
```

or if you wanted to return some view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ModelName model)
{
    return View("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks kosher, so either something critical is missing from your example code, or you need to view the generated HTML to see what's missing.

Comment: Somehow it works in IE9. What should I look for in thegenerated html? I amnot seeing any Java script error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you omit the code that actually displayed the view to the user? I'm unsure of how this would function without a bit more. I mocked up your code and put in what I considered correct.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Save()
    {
        var vm = new ModelTest();

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ModelTest model)
    {
        //do stuff with model 

        //Set a value in TempData -- Meets requirement of storing a status
        TempData["Message"] = "OK";
        //RedirectToRoute  -- Meets requirement of preventing multiple posts partially. Some javascript will also help with this
        RedirectToRoute("routename");
    }
```

Post happened as expected in FF 4.01/5.0

Your model looks ok, it's just the controller code appears lacking.

Hopefully this helps.